# Creating JWT in Java, hot to verifyi in Node?

Tags: java, node.js, jwt

How can a JWT created in Java with JJWT (https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) be verified using Node.js? If we create the JWT like below and print the value out:

```
byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("something");
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, SignatureAlgorithm.HS512.getJcaName());

JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(subject)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, key);

System.put.println(builder.compact());
```

Trying to decode the printed out string in Node.js results to invalid signature error:

```
var nJwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJKb2UifQ.dqJqRrJ1zDlNq79RAJqhbqme23Fq_Fh9M4MufE5AT8A7-c2yo3OgG71RMSsUxloceG0WaYwhz3WIprcdZsYY_Q',
secretKey = 'something';

var verifiedJwt = nJwt.verify(token,secretKey);

console.log(verifiedJwt);
```

The token value is not correct in the example above, just provided as an example.

Comment: How to verify, terrible screen resolution...

Comment: Did you mean to require `njwt` or `jsonwebtoken` ?

Comment: Also, please provide the actual token that is being produced by jjwt - this will help us debug :)

Comment: can you check below answer if it works for you?

Answer (score 1):

You're base64 decoding the String `something` when using JJWT, but you're not doing that when using nJwt.

The bytes of a String and the bytes resulting from Base64 decoding the same String are different byte arrays.  So your two code samples are using effectively different keys.

edit:

Also, for what its worth, to ensure key integrity guarantees, you should ensure that your key when using HMAC-SHA algorithms is equal to or greater than the hash output length.

For SHA-256, the output length is 256 bits, SHA-384 is 384 and SHA-512 is 512.  This implies a minimum key length of 32 bytes (32 ascii chars), 48 bytes, and 64 bytes, respectively.  Using `something` as a key (9 bytes) for HMAC-SHA-512 is not advisable.

This is why JJWT provides convenience key generators to ensure best practices:

```
byte[] hmacSha512Key = MacProvider.generateKey().getEncoded();
byte[] hmacSha384Key = MacProvider.generateKey(SignatureAlgorithm.HS384).getEncoded();
byte[] hmacSha256Key = MacProvider.generateKey(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256).getEncoded();
```

HTH!